# differents buttons, differents images? react native

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-application

I'm a student and I developing a mobile app with React Native.
My target is this image:
(https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/403580119714889736/407172407049060352/Apercu_bingo_2_choisir_invites.jpg)

I could write the code with independent buttons, the problem appears when I want to add different images to each button. (I'm waiting for the back dev to create a boucle to add all the images with the shortest code possible (looking forward for some loop ideas ;) ).

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Button from 'react-native-button';
import
{
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Text,
  TouchableHighlight,
  Alert,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback
}
from 'react-native';
import styles from './Styles';

class ToggleButton extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cont2}>
        <TouchableHighlight style={styles.bubblechoice} onPress={this.props.onPress}>
              <View style={[styles.overlay, this.props.selected ? {backgroundColor: '#3C1088'} : {}]}>
               <Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('./photo1.jpg')}/>
              </View>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>


    );
  }
}

export default class MyComponent extends Component
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inv1: false,
      inv2: false,

    };
  }
  updateChoice(type) {
    let newState = {...this.state};
    newState[type] = !newState[type];
    this.setState(newState);
  }
  render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.containerinvite}>
      <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}>
          <ToggleButton label='inv1' onPress={() => { this.updateChoice('inv1') } } selected={this.state.inv1}/>
          <ToggleButton label='inv2' onPress={() => { this.updateChoice('inv2') } } selected={this.state.inv2}/>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={() => {Alert.alert('OK');}}>
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.buttonText}>ok</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
     </View>
    ); 
  }
  onPress1 = () => {
    this.setState({
      inv1: !this.state.inv1
    });
  }
  onPress2 = () => {
    this.setState({
      inv2: !this.state.inv2
    });
  }
}
```

The result that I have is:
https://scontent-cdt1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/28580783_10216099091730046_1132055272_o.png?oh=fdb33bbe2b82f29cac1d80b8e25f269e&oe=5A9B2488&dl=1, https://www.facebook.com/
The thing is that the View that changes the status color can't be without children, so I can't just change the image from there. I tried different options but I'm still can manage different photos with independents buttons.

Answer (score 1):

From your parent component you should pass your photos to the child component and use that prop for your source instead of

```
<Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require('./photo1.jpg')}/>  =>> This is wrong.

<Image style={styles.bubblechoice} source={require(photoUrls)}/> =>> It should be like this.
```

If you have further questions about it do not hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for answer!
 I'm sorry but I don't understand... are you proposing to 'transfer' `<Image>` where exactly?
I already try to add it as a child of `<ToggleButton>` but I have an error because I leave `<View>` empty. :/
And, for the url, and maybe is a silly question because I'm starting with the React native world but, when I put the url (example: `https://url`) I have an editor mark (and a consequent error) in the ":"